# c# winform find client side shortcut path

Tags: c#, winforms, shortcut

I have an .exe file on sharing folder in network. I have a terminal server and terminals connect with  remote connection and work with my .exe files shortcuts. I need to reach with client side desktop page info.txt for filling some personal information to my .exe file. Is there a way for it?

Sarf.exe in 192.168.1.4 shareing folder. Clients ip is 192.168.1.5 and username are mkdepo2 ,depo etc. in their desktop they have Sarf.ink and info.txt both I need to read usernames desktop path info.txt file

Comment: please show us what you have tried so far and specify your question to a single problem

Comment: accessing file from desktop maybe difficult since the path to desktop include name of the user account logged in. So you may need the client to select the path for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're working in terminal server, you can find out the name of the host client by looking for this environment variable:

```
hostpc = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CLIENTNAME")
```